# Decrease resolution of vector shapes (polygon) i.e. reduce size and number of points in outer ring

Tags: vector, kml, kmz, resolution

I'm trying to get a kmz export down to less than 3 megabytes and am wanting to do so by reducing the number of points in my polygons' outer rings.

I've seen this concept in action when it comes to buffer resolutions. If I were to create a buffer around a point with a resolution of 1 it would be a square, if it had a res of 2 it would be an octagon, and so on.

Is there something similar I could do to simple polygons whose outside rings are too detailed for my purposes?

Thanks

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramer%E2%80%93Douglas%E2%80%93Peucker_algorithm

Comment: You can also lop off unnecessary precision (6 decimal places in decimal degrees gets you to hand-span precision), and z value is optional in KML if it's zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With @Vince's help, I found a number of ruby libraries so far, one of which I should be able to hack together to make this work. Thanks Vince

the `douglas_peucker` gem. https://rubygems.org/gems/douglas_peucker

I haven't even begun to actually solve this yet, but when I do, I imagine I'll be taking each `Polygon` and converting it into an `ExteriorRing`, then converting that into a `LineString`. That's what the douglas_peucker gem takes as input.

So theoretically I'll just run each `LineString` through this bad boy at a couple of different resolutions until I get it right, then convert those `LineStrings` back into `LinearRings`, then `Polygons` again.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you first try to compress you KML file, to create a [KMZ file](https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/kmzarchives?hl=el&csw=1).

Google earth is very happy with that method.

If you still you're above your threshold you can try more more complex techniques.

Comment: I already have, I meant to say kmz